# Unable to upload file to the server

Tags: php

This is my php file for uploading files, but i am getting an error like **no such directory** whats wrong with my code?

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$vdo=$_FILES['uf']['name'];     $target_path = "/photo";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
$target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uf']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
?>
```

**upload.php file is in the same folder wher my Photo directory is** any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Does the path exists? Does the path have the right permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on line 3, you are adding a slash before the directry name, it must be placed after the path name **$target_path="photo/";**

```
<?php
$vdo=$_FILES['uf']['name'];     $target_path = "photo/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
$target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uf']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `/` after the

`$target_path`

```
$target_path = "/photo/";
```

Due to this, the variable `$target_path` is getting folder name prepending to the

file name uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a path like this:

```
/photoTheFileName.ext
```

There are two problems with this:

First, you don't have a `/` between the directory name and the file name.

When you fix that:

```
$target_path = "/photo/";
```

Then the path is the filesystem path, and it will be from the *root* of the file system.

You said:

> upload.php file is in the same folder wher my Photo directory is

So you want the target path to be something like:

```
$target_path = "/hosts/www.example.com/htdocs/photo/";
```

… making the appropriate adjustments for your file system.